# Check if there is a 404 response error in controller- Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

I working on the Halo 5 API, and users can register with their gamer-tags. When they do, they can log in, and when they login, they can go to their profile to look up their stats for Halo 5. But obviously some users wont enter legit gamertags. And thats were I need some validation in my controller that returns the view for the profile.

Here is a simple example of the controller:

```
 public function index ($slug) {

        // Emblem URL.
        $getPlayerEmblemImage = app('App\Http\Controllers\Api\GetGeneralStatsController')->getPlayerEmblemImage($slug);

        // Get General Player Arena Stats
        $playerGeneralStats = app('App\Http\Controllers\Api\GetGeneralStatsController')->getPlayerArenaStats($slug);
        $playerGeneralStatsArray = $this->getPlayerGeneralStatsArray($playerGeneralStats);

        // Get the Spartan Rank and XP
        $spartanRank = json_decode($playerGeneralStatsArray['SpartanRank'], true);
        $XP = json_decode($playerGeneralStatsArray['Xp'], true);
        $Gamer_Tag = json_encode($playerGeneralStatsArray['Gamer_Tag'], true);

        $user = User::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();

        return view('profile.index',
            compact(
                'user',
                'spartanRank',
                'XP',
                'getPlayerEmblemImage',
                'Gamer_Tag',
            )
        );
    }
```

My problem is, if a user does not exist, it throws this error:

> ClientException in RequestException.php line 107:
>   Client error: `GET https://www.haloapi.com/profile/h5/profiles/some%20useer/spartan` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:

How can I do some checking, and return different results, if that player is not found?

Maybe something like this?

```
 public function index ($slug) {

  if (// Doesnt exist, show this) {
  // do some other code here
    return view('profile.index', compact('user'))

  } else {

  // Code here....

 return view('profile.index',
            compact(
                'user',
                'spartanRank',
            ))
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use exception handling here.

```
try{
    // Code here....

 return view('profile.index',
            compact(
                'user',
                'spartanRank',
            ))
}
} catch(ClientException $exception) {
{
    // do some other code here
    return view('profile.index', compact('user'))
}
```

Import `use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;` in your controller

use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

Comment: What do you mean in that comment when you say **Replace Exception with specific exception you want to catch** ?

Comment: instead of exception, use `NotFoundException`

Comment: actually I didn't the know the exception thrown, that's why I wrote it

Comment: Try with `ClientException` instead of `NotFoundHttpException `,

Comment: BTW, if you are able to achieve what you want by your solution, I don't think you need to use this solution

Comment: Alright, the ClientException works, now I just have to sort out my views. I believe I can figure that out, or just change my view. Thank You. Yam y solution works, but it just redirects back, without showing the profile, which I dont want.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Change code in App/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
 public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        // Flash a success message saying you have successfully registered.
        flash()->error('Error', 'That player has not played Halo, or does not exist.');

        return redirect()->back();

       // return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```